# Jquery help,hiding other elements when one is clicked

Tags: jquery, html

Can anyone help me with this,basically I want to make my divs hide when the other div is clicked cause I'm using 2 divs in same place but when I click both of them they both open on each other. I was thinking if it's possible to make it so when you click one the other hides

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#click').click(function() {
        $('#map').toggle('slow', function() { 

        });
    });

    $('#rubinez').click(function() {
        $('#css3droppanel').toggle('slow', function() { 

        });
    });

    $('#galleryy').click(function() {
        $('#rubb').toggle('1000',function() {

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Take a look at [jQuery accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: All this job could be very easy for you, in just a couple of jQuery lines just using CLASSes instead of all this IDs

Comment: Can you show your html? Could be as simple as $('#somediv').show().siblings().hide()

Answer (score 1):

.next() maybe can help you,

```
$('.box').live('click',function(){
  $(this).fadeOut(500,function(){
  $(this).next().css('display','block');
});
```

i dont understand your situation soo i made this 
http://jsfiddle.net/sejXA/